# Is there a way to wait for and read the next keyboard input?

Tags: c++

First time asking here.
I've been looking around for quite a while and couldn't find an answer anywhere.
I've had to build a calculator in C++ (boring stuff so tried to make it interesting) but couldn't find a way to wait for the next keyboard input and read it/store it. Something like keyboard events.

Cin requires the user to press enter every time and I don't want that. same for getchar, getch, cin.get(), etc...

If possible I'd like to avoid the inclusion other library than the basic ones.

Anyone knows how to ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

The standard C++ libraries do not provide single-character input functions. You will need to use something like the [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library, which provides functions to do this.